# URL Redirect, htaccess. Capture and insert after string if string is not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm hoping to get some help with an htaccess solution for the following redirects:

Case 1) the user enters domain.com it should redirect to domain.com/nl

Case 2) if the user enters domain.com/nl or domain.com/fr it should not redirect

Case 3) the user enters domain.com/some-path it should capture the url path and stick /nl in front of it, domain.com/nl/some-path

So far I've tried the following rule:

```
Redirect 301 ^((?!(?:)nl($)|(?:)fr($)).)*$ domain.com/nl/$1
```

However in Case 3, only the final character of the path is selected and not the whole 'some-path'.

Using multiple rules is ok too, but can it be done in a single rule?

Comment: Could you please do mention in your question from which URL to which URL you want to rewrite/redirect(samples only URLs would work) for better understanding of your question. Also share your htaccess file for better understanding, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in single rule like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(?:nl|fr)[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to work. Still having trouble using with wordpress multisite domain mapping, but it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For adding nl to home/base page.
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/nl [R=301,NE,L]

##For dealing with pages NOT starting with nl or fr here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(nl|fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```